# Character encoding in Geolocation with file_get_contents() / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, geolocation, file-get-contents

I call the Google geolocation service like this:

```
        $querystring = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&latlng=".$row['lat'].",".$row['lng'];

        $context = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'timeout' => 10
            )
        ));

        $f = file_get_contents($querystring, 0, $context);
        $f = json_decode($f);

        if(!isset($f->status) || $f->status != 'OK') continue;

        $f = $f->results[0];
        $location = $f->formatted_address;
```

I then insert the location into the database:

```
        //add the location to the database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta`
            (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
            VALUES
            (
                NULL,
                '".intval($row['ID'])."',
                'location',
                '".mysql_real_escape_string($location)."'
            )";
        if($location)   $insert = mysql_query($sql);
```

The problem: Some characters are not well displayed when I edit the wordpress posts.
Like for example
"R. HilÃ¡rio Riberio, 41-243 - PraÃ§a da Bandeira, Rio de Janeiro, 20270-180, Brazil"
should be
"R. Hilário Riberio, 41-243 - Praça da Bandeira, Rio de Janeiro, 20270-180, Brazil"

I use UTF-8 as character encoding on the website. But that's irrelevant, because phpMyAdmin shows the data is entered into the database with the broken characters as well.

How do I set the right character encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/mysql_set_charset) to set the **database connection encoding** to `'utf8'`, otherwise MySQL doesn't know that you're inserting UTF-8 encoded data. For more information, see [Handling Unicode in a Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- First, let's check that your PHP+browser are working correctly with UTF-8 in order to debug the real problems.  Place this in your PHP file and test in your browser:

  ```
  echo 'Filosofía: φιλοσοφία';
  ```

  You should be able to read it just like shown here (in spanish and greek)
- Once you're sure UTF-8 is working correctly, output the contents of your `$f` array:

  ```
  echo "<pre>\n" . print_r($f, true) . "\n</pre>";
  ```

  Check if contents look garbled.
- Make sure you tell MySQL that you want to use UTF-8:

  ```
  mysql_set_charset('utf8');
  ```

  Place this immediately *after* the `mysql_connect()` function.

Comment: Test #1 can help but it is not 100% reliable. I've seen too many real-life cases where the script would corrupt data before storing it and perfectly "un-corrupt" it before displaying it.